# Using continuity to show a linear function has constant derivative

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function and satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y),\,\,\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, show there exists an $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax,\,\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

From this, we know $f(x+0)=f(x)+f(0)\Rightarrow f(0)=0$.

We also know that for the interval $[c,d]=[c,c+t]$ for some $t$, the corresponding interval in the image is $[f(c),f(c)+f(t)]$.

Since the question doesn't say $f$ is differentiable, we can't use the definition of the derivative, which shows that the derivative is a constant, so I assume we must use IVT and choosing some clever interval. Though using IVT in this problem seems difficult, since it seems we want to select an arbitrary $x$ and then show $f(x)=ax$, but in IVT, we don't directly choose variables in the pre-image.

Using the definition of continuity just recovers the first identity: $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(x+h)=f(x)\Rightarrow \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(x)+f(h)=f(x)\Rightarrow f(0)=0$$.

Comment: Hint: First look at what happens for $x \in \mathbb Z$, then $x \in \mathbb Q$. Can you prove that there exists an $a \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=ax$ for all $x \in \mathbb Q$? Then you are almost done...

Comment: Title-question inconsistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

It's easy to show that $$f(q)=qf(1)$$
for all $q\in\mathbb Q$. Now use the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ to conclude.

Comment: Thanks, just trying to make the last part rigorous. Since $f$ is continuous, we have $\lim_{t\rightarrow x} f(t)=f(x),\,\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$. So given any $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $\epsilon>0$, there's a corresponding $\delta>0$ such that $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}, |x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, $\exists q\in\mathbb{Q}$ st $|f(x)-qf(1)|<\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small, and $q$ can be made arbitrarily close to $x$, the identity holds for real $x$. Last part seems shaky.

Comment: It's the idea, but you have to take $q$ such that $|x-q|<\delta$ (what is not precise in your argument). But a better way is: Let $x\in \mathbb R\backslash \mathbb Q$. By density of $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$, there is a sequence $(x_n)\subset \mathbb Q$ s.t. $$\lim_{n\to\infty }x_n=x.$$ Since $x_n\in\mathbb Q$ for all $n$, $$f(x_n)=x_n f(1).$$ By continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb R$,$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty }f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty }x_nf(1)=xf(1)$$ what prove the claim.